# Angular 6 Firebase Deploy Command - Error: "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at errorHandler..."

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

Since updating to Angular 6 I've received this message when trying to run the `firebase deploy` command after using `ng build --prod`.

Full error:

> i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
>   Running command: npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint
>   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Nick'
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at errorHandler (C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:213:18)
>       at C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
>       at cb (C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:215:22)
>       at C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:253:24
>       at C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
>       at f (C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
>       at afterExtras (C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:178:20)
>       at Conf. (C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:235:20)
>   C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:213
>     if (npm.config.get('json')) {
>                    ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at process.errorHandler (C:\Users\Nick Cook\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:213:18)
>       at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:391:27)
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>   exit code7

Comment: Anyone?........

Comment: Is there any problem with your `ng build --prod`?

Comment: No, the ng-build --prod command works fine

Comment: I think there was a problem with your `npm`. Try `cache verify` or reinstall it.